# How to arrange graphics using CSS two by two in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I use Leaflet map with recharts in ReactJS.
At the moment when user clicks on the map marker PopUp will display with six charts one below the other.
I want to style the graphics two under two in three lines.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

How do I style the code with css ?

The code:

```
      {coords.map(({ lat, lng }, index) => (
          <Marker position={[lat, lng]} icon={customMarker} key={index}>
            <div className="popup">
            <Popup maxWidth="500" maxHeight="auto" >
              {index + 1} is for popup with lat: {lat} and lon {lng}
              <div className="chart">
              <br /><br />
              Температура °C
              <ComposedChart width={400} height={200} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
              }}>
                <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Line type="monotone" dataKey="TA" fill='#f70000' stroke="#f56200" />
              </ComposedChart>
              </div>

              <div className="chart">
              <br /><br />
              Скорост на вятъра
              <ComposedChart width={400} height={200} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
              }}>
                <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Bar dataKey='WS' barSize={10} fill='#4287f5' />
              </ComposedChart>
              </div>

              <div className="chart">
              <br /><br />
              Валеж
              <ComposedChart width={400} height={200} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
              }}>
                <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Bar dataKey='RR' barSize={10} fill='#003cff' />
              </ComposedChart>
              </div>

              <div className="chart">
              <br /><br />
              Сняг
              <ComposedChart width={400} height={200} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
              }}>
                <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Bar dataKey='SR' barSize={10} fill='#5df5dc' />
              </ComposedChart>
              </div>

              <div className="chart">
              <br /><br />
              Относителна влажност %
              <ComposedChart width={400} height={200} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
              }}>
                <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Area type='monotone' dataKey='RH' fill='#8884d8' stroke='#f56200' />
              </ComposedChart>
              </div>

              <div className="chart">
              <br /><br />
              Атмосферно налягане
              <ComposedChart width={400} height={200} data={this.state.dats} margin={{
                top: 20, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20,
              }}>
                <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
                <XAxis dataKey="DATS" />
                <YAxis />
                <Tooltip />
                <Legend />
                <Area type='monotone' dataKey='APRES' fill='#8884d8' stroke='#f56200' />
              </ComposedChart>
              </div>
            </Popup>
            </div>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </LeafletMap>
```

I want `<ComposedChart/>` to be wrapped and group two under two charts in three lines.
I have imported CSS file in my code.

In the css file I paste this code:

```
.popup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart {
  width: 40%;
}
```

But I cannot see the changes.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-wiles-vrrw9)

Comment: I've tried to run and fix your code, but it seems there are quite some problems.. You should first break down your code in order to see why all these dependencies break eachother styles.

Comment: And you shouldn't use different implementations of libraries with eachother. Like you use Leaflet and react-leaflet

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/intro.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a huge [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) fan. In your use case, this can be fixed (and be [responsive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)) in just a couple of lines of css:

```
.popup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: I import className="popup" in the PopUp element and import className="chart" in Composed chart, after I paste your code into my css file but without result Can you give me full example ?

Comment: You should wrap the charts with `<div className="chart"></div>` and wrap popup with `<div className="popup"></div>`.

Comment: I will try tommorow

Comment: Jurrian I Update my question, can you check please.. I cannot see any changes ..

Comment: Hard to say with so little of your code. Can you make a reproducible demo? [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/)

Comment: If cannot see the map and shadow markers just copy this code into your vs code :)